# How to know if I'm using external or internal libraries in Java?

Tags: java, libraries

So, I have to write this code and it must use only internal Java libraries.

I have to read the HTML content of a URL page and I have managed to do so, but I'm not sure if I have only used internal libraries because I'm not so familiar with Java, can some explain to me please?

I read that if it starts with "Java" it means that is a internal library, but Im not sure.

Below there is a image of what I have used. Thank you.

[First pic: used in the main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgsYM.png)
[Second pic: used in the reader class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ1pt.png)

Comment: Look up the class names in the official documentation.  If you are using an internal library then it will be there.  I don't know which version of java you're using, but here are the docs for java 11: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html

Comment: Im using java version 11.0.3, for what Ive searched on this website that you've sent, apparently everything is internal, but still not exactly sure

Answer (score 1):

If you are not pulling any external dependancies, as external jar's, maven or gradle dependancies, just using what ever JDK provides, then you are using internal Java libraries.

In both of your images imports are from JDK (internal Java libraries).

For other import if it starts with `java` or `javax` most likely it is internal library as well.